# How to pass details from a SQL query to a details.php page

Tags: php, html

Very new to PHP so please go easy on me :)
I need to show the product details (manufacturer, tag number, etc) of a product if it's clicked by the user after being shown the results page. User types in a search form initially, then I get the catalogue_query.php to show the results, images, etc, that's all good. Each product has its own unique id which I thankfully get it to show in the url of the details.php page so I am doing something right.

However when I click on an item, even though I do get the "details.php" page shown with the correct id in the URL all it returns is the image and details for the very first item in the DB, not the actual item I clicked on - in other words the image and details do not match the id in the url.

Here is my code to show the results:

```
    <?php
        $query = $_POST ['query'];
        $db = mysqli_connect ('localhost','root','root','asset_catalog');
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
         {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
         }

        $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM assets WHERE Description LIKE '%$query%' OR Manufacturer LIKE '%$query%' ORDER BY Description ");


        echo "<table border='0'>

        <tr>

        </tr>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
         {
            if (($i % 5) == 0) echo "<tr>";
             echo "<td><img src='".$row['Image']."' id='queryimg'><br>
             <a href='details.php?ID=".$row['ID']."' style='color: #fff;'>{$row[Description]}</a></td>";
                if (($i % 5) == 4) echo "</tr>";
              $i++;
         }

        if ( $i > 0 && ($i-1) % 3 < 2) echo "</tr>";

        echo "</table>";

    ?>
```

And here is my php for the details.php page:

```
<?php           
                $db = mysqli_connect ('localhost','root','root','asset_catalog');
                // Check connection
                if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                    {
                        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                    }

                $ID = isset($_GET['ID']) ? (int) $_GET['ID'] : null;
                $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM assets WHERE ID = $ID");
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

                    echo "<table border='0'>

                    <tr>

                    </tr>";


                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td><img src='".$row['Image']."' id='queryimg_details'>
                        <br>
                        {$row[Description]}</a>
                        <br>
                        {$row[Manufacturer]}
                        <br>
                        {$row[Tag_Num]}</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";


        ?>
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction? I am lost as to what I am doing wrong - or not doing.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: While unrelated, using `ID = $ID` inside your SQL query is a very simple case of an SQL injection vulnerability. Either sanitize the value of the variable, or use bind parameters (I do not know how, as I am not proficient in PHP, but search for it), because people would be able to change your database extremely easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$row` can have multiple entries, so you should loop over it:

```
foreach($row as $r) {
    // do stuff with this row like $r['Image']
}
```

You might want to change the variables names too.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I might be misunderstanding your comment but in this case there really should be only one entry since all that should be shown in details.php is the one product and its details (1 image, 1 Mftcr, 1 Tag #). I'll play around with this though.

Comment: Ok - even so, it's still going to fetch an array of rows, but there will only be one row in this case. I recommend the `foreach` regardless, but you could also `echo $row[0]['Image']`.